# Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit that could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I'm developing the windows phone 8 map application, and to extend its functionality have installed the Windows Phone Toolkit with NuGet pakage installer. After installing Microsoft.Phones.Toolkit is added into the References and also a folder is created as Toolkit.Content.

While following this tutorial http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/maps-windows-phone-8-and-phone while adding the namespace xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" I get an error as **URI Reference to a namespace Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit that could not be found**

This results that i can't add any toolkit:MapExtensions on map.

If anybody have solution on this please let me know that will be much appriciated.

Thanks In advance,
Suraj.

Comment: Try deleting the reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit and then re-add it manually. Then delete and re-add your namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Pasted from the article you linked:

```
xmlns:maps=”clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps”
```

It looks like you switched some namespaces around. Try copying and pasting that to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, go down in that article you will see **How to use pushpins** section, and there you have to use the namespace _toolkit_. Which is the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

Here's what I did:

1) Uninstall WPtoolkit from package manager console using following command: **Uninstall-Package WPtoolkit**

2) Make sure you have Nuget version >= 2.1 installed. (You can check it by going to tools->Extensions and Updates->Installed)

3) Reinstall WPtoolkit

Hope it works.
Regards.